# Angular 7 how to get all child elements with custom directive attribtues

Tags: angular, angular-directive

Can anyone help me how to get all the elements with custom attribute in angular component?

I know how to get list of angular components ie.

```
@ViewChildren(CdkDropList) dropLists: QueryList<CdkDropList[]>;
```

But not sure how to get list of elements which has got the custom directives. Like in my example:

```
  <div>
    <input type="text"/>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-info" [tooltip]="one"></i>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text"/>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-info" [tooltip]="two"></i>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text"/>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-info" [tooltip]="three"></i>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text"/>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-info" [tooltip]="four"></i>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text"/>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-info" [tooltip]="five"></i>
  </div>
```

Here i need the component to get all the elements which has got [tooltip] attribute?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can achieve it by doing this way:

```js
@Component({ /* ... */ })
export class FooComponent {
 @ViewChildren(TooltipDirective, { read: ElementRef }) inputs: QueryList<ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>>;

  ngAfterViewInit () {
    this.inputs.forEach(input => {
      console.log(input.nativeElement)
    })
  }
}
```

### Edit: getting the value of the attribute

```js
@ViewChildren(TooltipDirective) inputsDirs: QueryList<TooltipDirective>;

  ngAfterViewInit () {
    this.inputsDirs.forEach(inputDir => {
      // The value of the attribute
      console.log(inputDir.tooltip)
      // The host element
      console.log(inputDir.hostElem.nativeElement)
    })
  }
```

#### tooltip.directive.ts

```js
constructor (public hostElem: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>) { }
```

Comment: Thank you. But i how do i get the value of the attribute?